# C Code for Deleting a Line

Tags: c, file, io

I am a C noob, and I was trying to make a program to delete a specific line. For this, I chose to copy the contents of the source file, skipping the line intended for deletion. In my original code, I wrote:

```
 while(read_char = fgetc(fp) != '\n')   //code to move the cursor position to end of line
{
    printf("%c",read_char);   //temporary code to see the skipped characters
}
```

which gave me lots of smileys.

In the end I found the code which gave the intended output:

```
read_char=fgetc(fp);
while(read_char != '\n')   //code to move the cursor position to end of line
{
    printf("%c",read_char);   //temporary code to see the skipped characters
    read_char=fgetc(fp);
}
```

But what is the actual difference between these two codes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assignment has lower priority than not-equal, so:

```
read_char = fgetc(fp) != '\n'
```

results in `read_char` getting a `0` or `1`, the result of comparing the result of the `fgetc()` call against `'\n'`.

You need parentheses:

```
 while((read_char = fgetc(fp)) != '\n')
```

which will assign the `fgetc()` result to `read_char` before comparing with `'\n'`.